# Is it possible to declare a template function with 'auto' return type as a friend of a class?

Tags: c++, templates, auto

How to declare the following function as a friend of a class

```
template <class T>
inline auto func(T & val)
{
    //return ...;
}

class A { friend auto func<A>(A & val); }
```

Comment: Did you try compiling it?

Comment: If you enable c++14 or c++17, you can

Comment: no offense, but a Q&A along the line of "Can it be done?" - "Yes" isnt very useful. Imho the question could be improved a lot if you included the error message you get when you tried it

Comment: @NathanOliver, yes, but my function does not compile, because it is in a namespace, see http://rextester.com/live/ORCJ33746

Comment: @Alberto Miola the code should compile with VS2017 and GCC 4.9.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky change `return func<A>(a);` to `bug::func<A>(a);` or even just `bug::func(a);` and it compiles just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is it legal?**

Yes, you can get it to work from `C++14` on.

**How to do it?**

You can do it like this ([see here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/UvsFNJ)):

```
class A;

template <class T>
inline auto func(T& val);

class A
{
    friend auto func<A>(A& val); 

    int j = 6;
};

template <class T>
inline auto func(T& val)
{
    return val.j;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    return func<A>(a);
}
```

However, I agree with the comments: the question could be improved if you provided an exact problem for which we could try finding an answer.

Comment: Now the question is why this code does not compile if the function is a namespace, see http://rextester.com/live/ORCJ33746

Comment: Yes, I forgot 'auto'. It compiles with VS2017.

Comment: Perfekt! Good to hear!

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky If the answer helped, would you mind to upvote?